# How to add json value in P tag in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Onclick of some tab I am creating para tag and on that I want to add some text. How to add those value dynamically.

Here is what I am trying.

**Onclick** of tab I am calling this method.

```
SomeMethod = function(){
    var para = document.createElement("P");
       para.setAttribute("id", "myUL");


    function getData(callback) {
        debugger;
        var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        httpRequest.open('GET', "../resource/para.json", true);
        httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (httpRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && httpRequest.status === 200) {
                callback(httpRequest.responseText);
            }
        };
        httpRequest.send();
    }

    getData(function(data) {
        var jsonc = JSON.parse(data);
        debugger;
   document.getElementById('myUL').innerHTML = jsonc[0].VALUE;
    });
}
```

My JSON data is

```
[{
    "ID" : 0,
    "VALUE" : "My 10000 Character text."

    }]
```

Comment: The issue with code at Question is that the dynamically created element is not appended to the HTML `document`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a second parameter at `getData` function, pass `para` as second parameter, set `.textContent` of `para` to result of `JSON.stringify()` with `jsonc` passed as parameter or `jsonc[0].VALUE`, pass `para` to `.appendChild()` to append the element to the `document`

JavaScript

```
para.className = "json";
```

```
// pass `para` to `getData()` call
callback(httpRequest.responseText, para);
```

```
// `element`: `para` passed at `callback`
getData(function(data, element) {
    var jsonc = JSON.parse(data);
    element.textContent = JSON.stringify(jsonc, null, 4); // or `jsonc[0].VALUE`
    document.body.appendChild(element);
    debugger;
});
```

CSS

```
p.json {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Once you have your element, you can use `innerHTML` to put stuff inside of it. So supposing you already parsed your json and the data you want is inside the `jsonc` variable you can do

```
para.innerHTML = jsonc[0].VALUE;
```

Comment: Here in `getData` function I am getting `inner html of null`. para is not defined it seems. I updated my question. Please have look

Comment: You have to also append `para` where you want it, with the `appendChild` method of the element that will contain it. Otherwise `getElementById` won't find it.

Comment: Would that dynamically work ? I mean after adding para can we use `getElementById()` to find that element.

Answer (score 1):

To add dynamic html to dynamically created element (i.e `p` tag) try this

```
//Jquery
$("#yourtabid").append("<p></p>")
$("#yourtabid").find('p').append(jsonc[0].value);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can follow below steps to add the json value to your para element here :

- Create a "p" Element
- add the innerHTML for the element
- Add the element to your tab

If you are adding the innerHTML later, append the child first and then add the innerHTML.

```js
var para = document.createElement("p");
para.innerHTML = "TEST";

// I'm guessing you have some Element with id "tab"
document.getElementById("tab").appendChild(para);
```

```html
<div id="tab"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use setAttribute() for adding values, I have tried and it is possible save json data as string but I don't prefer save as string directly hence you can add as Base64 encoded.

```
var Base64={_keyStr:"ABCDEFGHIJKL....................
var jsonData = [{
    "ID" : 0,
    "VALUE" : "My 10000 Character text."

}];
console.log(jsonData);

jsonDataStr = JSON.stringify(jsonData);
console.log(jsonDataStr);


var para = document.createElement("P");
document.body.appendChild(para);
para.setAttribute('data-custom',Base64.encode(jsonDataStr));
//para.setAttribute('data-custom',jsonDataStr);

var dataFromAtt = para.getAttribute('data-custom');
console.log(dataFromAtt);
```

[Base64 Cross-Browser Method (compressed)](https://scotch.io/quick-tips/how-to-encode-and-decode-strings-with-base64-in-javascript#toc-cross-browser-method-compressed) you can find Base64 algorithm.

Comment: How is `base64` related to Question?

Comment: "I don't prefer save as string directly" also you can use without Base64